# ccf(): how to use "acf object" parameter?

Tags: r

I am trying to find out how to use ccf() with "acf object" parameters, but my simple example scripts fails with a cryptic message:

```
require(stats)
require(graphics)

#UKLungDeaths {datasets} 
ldeaths.acf<-acf(ldeaths)
mdeaths.acf<-acf(mdeaths)

ccf(mdeaths.acf, fdeaths.acf)
```

> Error in .cbind.ts(list(...), .makeNamesTs(...), dframe = dframe, union = FALSE) : 
>    incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

I am stuck (don't even understand why cbind get involved here), so please explain how to make this type of call work.

Comment: Can't you use `ccf(ldeaths, mdeaths)`? The documentation says that `ccf` accepts "acf"  objects, but looking at the code, I don't understand how that is supposed to work. Maybe submit a bug report?

Comment: Why do you want to use `acf` objects in `ccf`? This should be directly `ccf(ldeaths, mdeaths)`.

Comment: Well, my principal reason for wanting the acf objects is that the correlations are a compact representation of the info I need. If ccf() worked <a href="http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/acf" title="Arguments:  &quot;acf&quot; object.">as advertised</a> then I can work with the much smaller (and tidier) ACF list instead of the raw timeseries.

Comment: Moreover, there is a technical reason for wanting to go through acf objects: my data are in xts format, for which ccf() does not work directly.